# Selecting MAX(DATEDIFF()) for every debtor/customer in database

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have the following query that works for my purpose of research (for a single debtor):

```js
SELECT MAX(DATEDIFF(r.next_created, r.created))
    FROM (

    # finds each created and the next consecutive one in the table
    SELECT r1.created as created, (

        # finds the next consecutive created
        SELECT created
        FROM (db) r2
        WHERE r2.created > r1.created
        ORDER BY created ASC
        LIMIT 1
    ) as next_created

    FROM (db) r1
    ORDER BY r1.created) as r
```

However, I would very much like to be able to expand this to every single debtor_id in my database. Do you guys have any input, as to how I can do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT r.debtor, MAX(DATEDIFF(r.next_created, r.created))
FROM (SELECT r1.*
             (SELECT r2.created
              FROM db r2
              WHERE r2.debtor = r1.debtor AND r2.created > r1.created
              ORDER BY r2.created ASC
              LIMIT 1
             ) as next_created
      FROM db r1
     ) r
GROUP BY r.debtor;
```

This assumes that your table has a column called `debtor` (or something) that identifies what you care about.